# how to take a string out of a set in awk

Tags: string, awk, split

I have got following example strings, but there could be anything, so do not stick to the names.

```
apple = green
pie = brown
```

I want to get separately 'apple' and 'green' and so on and order them in an array.

```
array [0,0] = apple
array [0,1] = green
array [1,0] = pie
array [1,1] = brown
```

How do I split a string in awk into two parts before and after '=' sign?

Do I have to use sub or split functions?

Comment: awk -F '= ' '{print $1}' will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention and as implemented by awk builtin functions, awk arrays start at 1, not zero, so your array should start with `array[1,1] = apple`. Also, if you have GNU awk you can use true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk -F' = ' '
{ array[NR][1]; split($0,array[NR]) }
END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) printf "array[%d][%d] = %s\n",i,j,array[i][j]}
' file
array[1][1] = apple
array[1][2] = green
array[2][1] = pie
array[2][2] = brown
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the array that you want:

```
awk -F' = ' '{ array[NR-1,0] = $1; array[NR-1,1] = $2 }' file
```

Set the field separator to `=` using the `-F` switch and assign the fields, using the record number `NR` (subtracting 1 as it begins at 1, not 0).

Comment: `-F` is what is used to set the field separator.

Comment: The question `What does -F means?` means you need to get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins!